# Curious about some Java out.Write output

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

When I run the following code:

```
int i = 0

 try {
        fstream = new FileWriter(filename);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
while (i < 100) {
            out.write("My Name is Bobby Bob");
            out.write(i);
            out.newLine();
            i++;
}
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getClass();
    }
```

I get the following in my output file:

```
My Name is Bobby Bob
```

x100

each one is followed by a weird symbol. Male sign, female sign etc etc.

My question is and its more of a curious one. What causes these weird symbols to appear? I was expecting numbers as it counted up. Where are these symbols pulled from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

out is a RandomAccessFile ?

I think you are using write(byte) instead of write(String), so you are writting the byte X, see ASCII TABLES for representations.

Try

```
write(""+i);
```

Looking at BufferedWriter java api:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)

it says that it writes the integer representation of a char, for your understanding.

If you want to print the value **0** you have to write **48** as this image represents:
[image: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif]

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
out.write(i);
```

it writes the `(char) i` not the number in i as text.

If you want to write `i` as a number use print

```
out.print(i);
```

or

```
out.write(String.valueOf(i));
```

or

```
out.write(""+i);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing single characters that are specified by the given int value, and not a character representation of the variable i.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`. The `PrintStream.write(int)` method writes a single byte to the output stream with the byte value specified. So you're not writing the integers 0 through 100, you're writing the bytes 0 through 100. You probably want `print(int)` instead of `write(int)`.